# json, listadapters and multiple on click activity for listviews

Tags: android, json, listview, listadapter

I am using api calls to pull out a json entry and fill in my list view. The problem I am having is implementing different listeners inside of my list view. The list view looks like this:

[image]

The listView is to implement an onItemClick listener and a checkBox listener. Till now I was able to populate the listView and generate the onItemClick listener, but I failed to implement the checkBox listener. From my tries I am only able to invoke this checkBox listener after the  listView item is clicked and only for one of the checkBoxes(out of several).

The code looks like this for now:

```
public class Allprojects extends SherlockListActivity{


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> all_list;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ActionMode mMode;
    ListView list;
    Layout layoutList;
    CheckBox projectCheckBox;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.projectlist);

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    bar.setNavigationMode(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);


    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.actionbarnavlist, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    OnNavigationListener mNavigationlistner = new OnNavigationListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    switch (itemPosition) {
    case 0:
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already viewing all projects", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
    case 1:
    Intent intent = new Intent(Allprojects.this, Myproject.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    break;

    default:
    break;
    }

    return false;
    }
    };
    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mNavigationlistner);
    bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);

    all_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Asyncprojectlist connection = new Asyncprojectlist();
    connection.execute();
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionCallBack = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu_add_project, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.cancelActionMenu:
    break;
    case R.id.addToProjectsMenu:
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
    return false;
    }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("press to start selection");
    }

    private class Asyncprojectlist extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    JSONArray JSar;
    JSONObject JSob;
    String project_title, project_sector;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(Allprojects.this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    UserFunctions user = new UserFunctions();
    JSob = user.allprojects();
    try {
    JSar = JSob.getJSONArray("data");

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<JSar.length(); i++){
    try {
    JSONObject newobj = JSar.getJSONObject(i);
    project_title = newobj.getString("title");
    project_sector = newobj.getString("sector");

    HashMap<String, String> single = new HashMap<String, String>();
    single.put("title", project_title);
    single.put("sector", project_sector);

    all_list.add(single);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
//  Log.i("json object", JSar.toString());
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), all_list, R.layout.projectlist_frame, 
    new String[]{"title","sector"}, new int[]{R.id.projecttitle, R.id.projectsector});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    list = getListView();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
    int position, long id) {

    Intent toindividual = new Intent(Allprojects.this, Individual_project.class);
    try {
    toindividual.putExtra("nid", JSar.getJSONObject(position).getString("id"));
    startActivity(toindividual);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    projectCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    projectCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(projectCheckBox.isChecked()){
    Log.i("CHECKED", "CHECKED");
    startActionMode(mActionCallBack);
    }else{
    Log.i("UNCHECKED","UNCHECKED");
    startActionMode(mActionCallBack).finish();
    }
    }
    });

    }

    });


    }


    }   
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare your `projectCheckBox `? In XML? why there is only one `projectCheckBox ` while there are many rows in `ListView`?

Comment: the number of rows in the ListView is indefinite that is why the api is called. check out edited question for projectCheckBox declaration. @user2652394 ... there is only one declaration of the checkBox because the listView's layout is made that way. that is why i need help.

Comment: I suggest you implement your own `Adapter` instead of using `SimpleAdapter`, that way you can also implement event handling for each and every `CheckBox` of rows in your `ListView`. One more thing, instead of implementing `onClick`, I think `onCheckChanged` is the right thing to do in this case. Hope this helps.

Comment: well the problem is that i have no idea how to do that because of the api references to the strings and the number of projects being unknown ... could you help with a sample code ? @user2652394.

Comment: Since I dont have time to give you a specific code, check some custom adapter tutorials, those will give you the ideas to implement, start with this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html . Hope this helps.